# JavaScript induced style changes are not permanent

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Okay, I change the appearance of links using JavaScript. When I change the content of a hard-coded link, it sticks in that the changed color and underlining remains when the cursor is not hovering above it. However, when the content of a DIV has been changed using JavaScript, the style changes do not stick.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bla bla</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="style/kim.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Kim.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="topNav">
        <ul>
          <li onClick="changeNav('design')"><a href="#" id="design">Design</a></li>
          <li onClick="changeNav('code')"><a href="#" id="code">Programming</a></li>
          <li onClick="changeNav('science')"><a href="#" id="science">Science</a></li>
          <li onClick="changeNav('Kim')"><a href="#" id="Kim">Kim</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="subNav"> 
        <script>changeNav("design");</script> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p id="mainText">Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
var topNavNames = ["design", "code", "science", "Kim"];
var subNavCode = ["<ul><li onClick=\"loadPHP('design/websites.php', 'sub0')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub0\">Websites</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('design/graphics.php', 'sub1')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub1\">Graphics</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('design/flash.php', 'sub2')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub2\">Flash</a></li></ul>",
                "<ul><li onClick=\"loadPHP('code/interactive.php', 'sub0')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub0\">Interactive applets</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('code/statistics.php', 'sub1')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub1\">Statistics</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('code/wings.php', 'sub2')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub2\">Wings</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('code/3D.php', 'sub3')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub3\">3D</a></li></ul>", 
                "<ul><li onClick=\"loadPHP('science/3D.php', 'sub0')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub0\">3D</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('science/ssd.php', 'sub1')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub1\">Sexual Size Dimorphism</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('science/shape.php', 'sub2')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub2\">Wing shape</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('science/phylogenetics.php', 'sub3')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub3\"><i>Drosophila</i> phylogenetics</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('science/communitygenetics.php', 'sub4')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub4\">Community Genetics</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('science/biodiversity.php', 'sub5')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub5\">Biodiversity</a></li></ul>", 
                "<ul><li onClick=\"loadPHP('Kim.php', 'sub0')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub0\">Who is Kim?</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('animals/horses.php', 'sub1')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub1\">Horses</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('animals/birds.php', 'sub2')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub2\">Birds</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('private/outdoors.php', 'sub3')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub3\">Outdoors</a></li><li onClick=\"loadPHP('contact.php', 'sub4')\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"sub4\">Contact</a></li></ul>"];
function changeNav(target) {
for (var i = 0; i<topNavNames.length; i++) {
    if (target == topNavNames[i]) {
        document.getElementById("subNav").innerHTML=subNavCode[i];
        document.getElementById(topNavNames[i]).style.color="#F7EDAA";
        document.getElementById(topNavNames[i]).style.borderBottom="thin solid #F7EDAA";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(topNavNames[i]).style.color="#EEE";
        document.getElementById(topNavNames[i]).style.borderBottom="thin solid #111";
    }
  }
}

function loadPHP(url, target) {
for (var i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    if(document.getElementById(target)!=null) {
        if (("sub"+i) == target) {
            document.getElementById(target).style.color="#F7EDAA";
            document.getElementById(target).style.borderBottom="thin solid #F7EDAA";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(target).style.color="#EEE";
            document.getElementById(target).style.borderBottom="thin solid #111";
        }
    }
}
}
```

if I subsequently remove the:

```
else {
        document.getElementById(target).style.color="#EEE";
        document.getElementById(target).style.borderBottom="thin solid #111";
    }
```

from the loadPHP function, it changes the style, but does not reset it when the next link is clicked.

I observed this behavior in FireFox, Internet Exploder and Chrome.

Added: CSS code:

```
body {
background-color: #111111;
color: #DDD;
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
overflow: auto;
}
.banner {
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 100px;
}
.main {
position: relative;
width: 80%;
left: 25px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #EEE;
}
a:hover {
border-bottom: thin solid #F7EDAA !important;
color: #F7EDAA !important;
}
.topNav {
height: 45px;
position: relative;
left: 100px;
font-size: large;
border: thin solid #111;
}
#subNav {
height: 45px;
position: relative;
left: 100px;
top: 2px;
border: thin solid #111;
}
.topNav li, #subNav li {
float: left;
margin: 10px 15px;
}
.topNav ul,  #subNav ul {
list-style: none;
padding: 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px;
position: relative;
left: -100px;
}
.content {
position: relative;
left: 15px;
padding: 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px;
}
.content p {
padding: 5px 5px;
margin: 10px 15px;
left: -100px;
}
```

Comment: Well i doubt it's gonna fix your stuff but tiny tip - using the escapes on single-quotes (aka `\'`) is unnecessary because the string is enclosed in double-quotes already (which of course means THOSE need escapes, like you have).  Can you post the rest of your code for the page?

Comment: Thank you, yes, you were totally right, fixed it because it will read somewhat easier. I wil expend the code for the whole page.

Comment: If you put this up on JSfiddle or codepen, it would be easier for people to fork and help you out.

Comment: I tried adding it to JSFiddle, but that does not work: Here is the version there: http://jsfiddle.net/KimvdLinde/dLX45/

Comment: You make the changes to specific elements. When you update the content of the `div`, those elements get destroyed and new ones are created. You'd have to apply the style to the new elements as well.

Comment: The content of the div 'subNav' only gets updated when I click on an element in div topNav. The topNav style changes stick. When I subsequently click on a entry in the subNav bar, I do not change the content of that div, I only change the style. So, replacement of the div content is not the issue because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The following code does not do the right thing:

```
function loadPHP(url, target) {
for (var i = 0; i<subNavNames.length; i++) {
    if (target == subNavNames[i]){
        document.getElementById(target).className="selected";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(target).className="notSelected";
    }
}
```

While this code does produce the right result:

```
function loadPHP(url, target) {
    for (var i = 0; i<subNavNames.length; i++) {
    if (target == subNavNames[i]) {
        document.getElementById(subNavNames[i]).className="selected";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(subNavNames[i]).className="notSelected";
    }
}
```

The difference is that in the first example, and in the example of the original question, I use the variable passed on in the method (target), to find the element. In the second, I use the appropriate element from a array that I have added to the list. I am not sure WHY this behaves differently, but it does.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you´re using the wrong technology to achieve your goal. What you need to do is to write your styles in a css stylesheet, and then add or remove classes to your elements using js if you want. (You can also do this through something called specificity, a little far ahead from the scope of your question)

Also think that if there is some bug in your script, or a third party script called in your page, JS may break and it won´t process your styling changes.

So, add the basic styling to your elements through css in the initial markup, so you will be sure that your elements will have always a basic styling, and then if you want use the equivalent to .addClass or removeClass jQuery methods.

In that way you will be always sure that your frontend will have always a safe styling, won´t break if js is not loaded, and separation of concerns will be properly implemented.

Regards.

Comment: Didn't think of adding the classes itself using javascript. Going to try it now.

Comment: Changed the code to change class instead of inline style elements, but the problem seems to persist.